# Create a message with link without preview in Google chat

Tags: google-api, google-chat

I like to send a message using [Google chat](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/message-formats/text#messages_that_mention_all_users) webhook api.
Is there a way to add a link, but the message does not generate link preview along with it.
I can use cards which does not generate. But it looks like a unnecessary effort.

If you manually add a message in chat, you can remove the preview card. I like to do the same with API.

Answer (score 2):

For plain text links, there is no way to remove the preview card yet.

as Google stated in [their docs](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/spaces.messages)

> Plain-text body of the message. The first link to an image, video, or web page generates a preview chip. You can also @mention a Google Chat user, or everyone in the space.

But the workaround is to use alternate link text. As stated in their [docs](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/guides/message-formats/text#include-links) to create alternate link, we need just use syntax `<https://example.com|example.com>`. It also recommended by google itself in [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/188457860)

but its might workaround doesn't work recently. There is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/286269821) regarding that. You can upvote(+1) the issue to make google team prioritized that.